# Angular: a better way to filter when you're only expecting one result

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the following angular code to get one item out of a list.

```
<span ng-repeat="metro in metros | filter:{id:event.metro_id}">
    {{metro.timezone}}
</span>
```

So there's a list of `metros` and I'm filtering the list for metros where the `id` matches `event.metro_id`.  The thing is, for my scenario I know there's always going to be 1, and only 1, match for this filter and it feels silly to use a `ng-repeat` just to get that one element.  Is there a more elegant way to do this.  My goal is to do it all in the HTML template and avoid placing more code in the angular controller.

Comment: do the filtering in controller...

Comment: As I said in the post, "My goal is to do it all in the HTML template and avoid placing more code in the angular controller"

Comment: but then its less performant... as per me - having logic is javascript is better than having it in html. Html is not the correct place to hold programming logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could slightly modify your `metros` structure (only in favour of what you want to), to be a collection with id's as properties, then you could do like this in HTML:

```
<span ng-show="event.metro_id">
    {{metros[event.metro_id].timezone}}
</span>
```

I meant to have `metros` like this:

```
$scope.metros = {
  "25" : {
    "timezone" : 25,
    "foo" : "bar"
  },
  "35" : {
    "timezone" : 35,
    "foo" : "bar"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup, I ended up using underscorejs to do exactly that.